# What is the equivalent of sp_refreshsqlmodule (sys stored procedure) in SQL Server for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

What is the equivalent of  sp_refreshsqlmodule (sys stored procedure) in SQL Server for PostgreSQL?

```
sp_refreshsqlmodule
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refreshsqlmodule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

> Updates the metadata for the specified non-schema-bound stored
> procedure, user-defined function, view, DML trigger, database-level
> DDL trigger, or server-level DDL trigger in the current database.
> Persistent metadata for these objects, such as data types of
> parameters, can become outdated because of changes to their underlying
> objects.

Comment: You might describe its role in SQL Server and link to some documentation. Would help the case.

Comment: I don't think Postgres has the problem that `sp_refreshsqlmodule` needs to solve in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres views, procedures and functions are created in a similar way as SQL Server's "with schema binding".

So there is no equivalent procedure in Postgres, because there is no need for it.